# Como Ordenar Dados de Modelos Relacionados?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, relacionamento

Tenho o seguinte relacionamento na minha aplicação:

Modelo **Cliente**:

```
class Cliente extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'clientes';

    public function Usuario(){ 
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Admin\Usuario', 'id_cliente');
    }    
}
```

Modelo **Usuario**:

```
class Usuario extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'usuarios';

    public function Cliente(){ 
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Admin\Cliente', 'id_cliente'); 
    }
}
```

Porém preciso ordenar os resultados quando eu chamo todos os usuários do cliente na minha view:

```
@foreach($Cliente->Usuario as $usuario)...
```

Esse é apenas um exemplo, tenho diversos relacionamentos na minha aplicação que eu preciso aplicar esse filtro de ordenação, como eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: +1 importante essa pergunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No Laravel é possível fazer o carregamento prévio dos resultados dos relacionamentos de um determinado model. Assim, juntamente com esse carregamento, você pode também adicionar condições que serão aplicadas aos relacionamentos que serão carregados junto com sua consulta. Isso é feito através do método `with` (Sempre que quiser usá-lo, ele deve ser o primeiro método a ser chamado).

No controller, você pode fazer assim:

```
$with['usuarios'] = function ($query) {
    return $query->orderBy('nome');
};

$cliente = Cliente::with($with)->find($id);
```

Ou você também pode separar os dois, e fazer uma segunda query para os usuários baseado na query do cliente.

```
 $cliente = Cliente::find($id);

 $usuarios = $cliente->usuarios()->orderBy('nome')->get();
```

No segundo exemplo, você teria que fazer o `foreach` em `$usuarios`.

## Ordenando a coleção

Também é possível ordenar os dados de relacionamento depois da conclusão da consulta.

Por exemplo, quero ordenar meus usuários que estão relacionados com um cliente pelo nome. E depois quero listá-los novamente e ordená-los pela data de atualização.

Ao invés de fazer duas consultas, você pode fazer assim:

```
#controller

 $cliente = Cliente::with('usuarios')->find($id);

 $ordenadores['nome'] = function ($usuario)
 {
      return $usuario->nome;
 };

 $ordenadores['atualizacao'] = function ($usuario)
 {
        return $usuario->created_at;
 };

 return view('minha_view', compact('cliente', 'ordenadores'));
```

Aí na view, você pode fazer assim:

```
#view

@foreach($cliente->usuarios->sortBy($ordenadores['nome']) as $usuario)

@endforeach


@foreach($client->usuarios->sortBy($ordenadores['atualizacao']) as $usuario)

@endforeach
```

**Nota**: Em alguns casos, não é necessário usar um `Callback` no `sortBy`. Basta passar o nome do campo como argumento de `sortBy`, para ordenar os dados na Collection.

```
@foreach($client->usuarios->sortBy('created_at') as $usuario)

@endforeach
```

**Dica**

Geralmente, para manter a legibilidade dos métodos do seu model, sugiro que utilize singular para relacionamentos (um para um) como `belongsTo` e `hasOne`, e plural para `hasMany` ou `belongsToMany` e afins (múltiplos relacionamentos).

Comment: muito bom mano, na verdade mandei um vai que cola e funcionou até sem fazer as modificações no controller, apenas colocando o nome do campo que eu queria ordenar no "sortBy". ->sortBy('nome'). Muito obrigado msm!

Comment: @RaylanSoares esqueci de mencionar que internamente o Laravel já faz isso (transforma a key em callback) para usar no sortBy.

Comment: pow muito show mano

Comment: Se precisar, tembém tem o `sortByDesc('nome')`