# É possível ordenar o resultado do Model pai pelo Model filho?

Tags: laravel

### Controller

```
$menu       = MenuLoginPermission::with('submenu')
            ->where('id_empresa_login', '=', $idUser)
            ->get();
```

### Model MenuLoginPermission

```
class MenuLoginPermission extends Model
{
    public function menu(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Menu', 'id_menu', 'id');
    }
    public function submenu(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Submenu', 'id_menu', 'id_menu');
    }
}
```

Não estou conseguindo fazer a ordenação do Model Pai por um campo **ORDER** do Model Filho.

Isso é possível ?

Tentei com **WhereHas** e **Eager Loading**, mas não deu certo.

Em último caso farei um **LeftJoin**. Mas antes, queria saber se tem solução de outra maneira.

**Model Pai** = MenuLoginPermission

**Model Filho** = Menu

**Campo da Tabela** Menu = Order

Comment: Relacionado: [Como Ordenar Dados de Modelos Relacionados?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123991/como-ordenar-dados-de-modelos-relacionados/124002#124002)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe uma forma de ordenar com o [**resultado da coleção**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-collections), ou seja, [***classe collection***](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-collections), com o comando [***sort***](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-sort)

***Exemplo:***

**Código:**

```
$collect = collect(['d' => 2, 'a' => 1, 'z' => 0]);
return $collect->sort(function($a, $b){
    return $a == $b ? 0: ($a > $b ? 1 : -1);
})->toArray();
```

**Saida:**

```
{ "z": 0, "a": 1, "d": 2}
```

---

***No seu código:***

```
  MenuLoginPermission::with('submenu')
   ->where('id_empresa_login', '=', $idUser)
   ->get();
   ->sort(function($p1,$p2)
     {
        $a = $p1->menu->order;
        $b = $p2->menu->order;
        return $a == $b ? 0: ($a > $b ? 1 : -1);
     }, SORT_REGULAR, false)
    ->toArray();
```

---

A forma mais natural seria com `leftJoin`

```
MenuLoginPermission::with('submenu')
  ->where('id_empresa_login', '=', $idUser)
  ->leftJoin('submenu', 'submenu.id_menu','=','menuloginpermission.id_menu')  
  ->orderBy('submenu.order','asc')
  ->select('menuloginpermission.*')
  ->get();
```

Existe a forma de escrever um item anônimo com o comando [***with***](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), mas, o resultado da ordenação não influencia o *item principal*.

Comment: Vou testar o método `sort`. E sim, a maneira mais natural seria usando o `leftJoin`.

Comment: Uma informação, eu não sei todos os campos das relações se por ventura algum não condizer, me avise @Gumball!

Comment: No caso do Sort, ali nas variáveis de ordenação, seria `$p1->menu->order` e não **submenu**.

Comment: Bom, funcionou do jeito que queria. Porém, no `@foreach` da minha **view** eu estou usando a **$key** para fazer uma conta. E como ordenou o collection, mantém os índices, mas era pra começar do zero independente as situações.

Comment: @Gumball, antes de mais nada a sua pergunta foi respondida, o `foreach` eu não sei o que está fazendo, não tem essa informação na questão!

Comment: A questão não é o **foreach**, e sim que a função **sort** ordena os valores, mas as chaves permanecem. Apenas queria que começasse do 0 independente de ordenação... Agora só porquê não falei nada na pergunta fica com essas graças de não poder responder... que política é essa ?

Comment: Eu não disse que iria responder ou não, eu só disse que não tem a informação na sua pergunta, ou tem que eu não percebi? se quiser e puder coloque na sua questão e edite para que eu termine, raiva não leva a nada...

Comment: Fiz o contador na mão. Obrigado por tirar a dúvida.

Comment: @Gumball Acho que cabe aqui uma leitura ao http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. As perguntas devem ter o máximo de detalhes possível, quando isso não ocorre fica difícil dar uma resposta adequada. Essa é a política do site. Evite comportamentos que leve à reclamações por parte dos usuários: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5379/101